# How to get all the next page links from a webpage?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, css-selectors, web-crawler

I've written some script in python to get all the links leading to the next page. However, it works fine only to a certain extent. The highest number of next page links is 255. Running my script, I get first 23 links along with the last page link but between them [24 to 254] are missing. How can I get all of them? Here is what I'm trying with:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

page_link = "https://www.yify-torrent.org/search/1080p/"
b_link = "https://www.yify-torrent.org"

def get_links(main_link):
    links = []
    response = requests.get(main_link).text
    tree = html.fromstring(response)
    for item in tree.cssselect('div.pager a'):
        if item.attrib["href"] not in links:
            links.append(item.attrib["href"])
    for link in links:
        print(b_link + link)

get_links(page_link)
```

Elements within the next page links lies:

```
<div class="pager"><a href="/search/1080p/" class="current">1</a> <a href="/search/1080p/t-2/">2</a> <a href="/search/1080p/t-3/">3</a> <a href="/search/1080p/t-4/">4</a> <a href="/search/1080p/t-5/">5</a> <a href="/search/1080p/t-6/">6</a> <a href="/search/1080p/t-7/">7</a> <a href="/search/1080p/t-8/">8</a> <a href="/search/1080p/t-9/">9</a> <a href="/search/1080p/t-10/">10</a> <a href="/search/1080p/t-11/">11</a> <a href="/search/1080p/t-12/">12</a> <a href="/search/1080p/t-13/">13</a> <a href="/search/1080p/t-14/">14</a> <a href="/search/1080p/t-15/">15</a> <a href="/search/1080p/t-16/">16</a> <a href="/search/1080p/t-17/">17</a> <a href="/search/1080p/t-18/">18</a> <a href="/search/1080p/t-19/">19</a> <a href="/search/1080p/t-20/">20</a> <a href="/search/1080p/t-21/">21</a> <a href="/search/1080p/t-22/">22</a> <a href="/search/1080p/t-23/">23</a> <a href="/search/1080p/t-2/">Next</a> <a href="/search/1080p/t-255/">Last</a> </div>
```

The results I'm getting are like [curtailed to the last five links]:

```
https://www.yify-torrent.org/search/1080p/t-20/
https://www.yify-torrent.org/search/1080p/t-21/
https://www.yify-torrent.org/search/1080p/t-22/
https://www.yify-torrent.org/search/1080p/t-23/
https://www.yify-torrent.org/search/1080p/t-255/
```

Comment: Do you need lxml? Or do other parsers work? Say, bs4.

Comment: Thanks cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, for your comment. I didn't try other than lxml. Anyways, giving it a try with beautifulsoup and let you know.

Comment: No luck, unfortunately with bs4 either. Results are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Answer provided by @kaze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45359499/how-to-get-all-the-next-page-links-from-a-webpage/45359651#45359651) obviously should return you 255 pages, but if you need to get all links dynamically without hardcoding total pages number, you might try

```
r = requests.get("https://www.yify-torrent.org/search/1080p/")
tree = html.fromstring(r.content)
page_number = tree.xpath("//div[@class='pager']/a[.='Last']/@href")[0].split("/")[-2].replace("t-", "")

for page in range(int(page_number) + 1):
    requests.get("https://www.yify-torrent.org/search/1080p/t-%s/" % page)
```

Comment: Thanks sir Andersson, for your answer. I didn't notice your answer until now. Your answer always rocks. Will get back to you after running it. btw, the solution kaze provided is not applicable in this case unless twisted otherwise.

Comment: Yes it works. Btw, please take a look into this link to see whether I'm doing thing in the right way cause it is very slow. I'm afraid I'm overwriting stuffs. Thanks sir. "https://www.dropbox.com/s/j62wcgiwubc58cu/For%20sir%20Andersson.txt?dl=0"

Comment: yeah, you're doing the same work twice. You don't have to scrape links with `for item in tree.xpath("//div[@class='pager']/a/@href"):`... if you need just links list, try `links = ["https://www.yify-torrent.org/search/1080p/t-%s/" % page for page in range(int(page_number) + 1)]`

Comment: You are such a gem, sir. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if the link structure isn't infereable you would have to 'walk the site', but here you might as well generate the links yourself, like so:

```
for i in range(1,256):
    print('https://www.yify-torrent.org/search/1080p/t-%s/' % i)
```

Comment: This should work, but how does your script knows that there are 255 pages? Can you provide solution without hardcoding total pages number?

Comment: typically, you can check for status codes while scraping. i.e. `response = requests.get(currenturl)` and then `break` if `response.status_code == '404'`. however, upon testing, this doesn't seem to work in your use case. So another possible solution would be to compare your last response to your current response and `break` if equal.

Answer (score -1):

Your script looks correct as it is. Looking at the HTML for that page, I see this:

```html
<a href="/search/1080p/t-2/">2</a> 
<a href="/search/1080p/t-3/">3</a> 
<a href="/search/1080p/t-4/">4</a> 
<a href="/search/1080p/t-5/">5</a> 
<a href="/search/1080p/t-6/">6</a> 
<a href="/search/1080p/t-7/">7</a> 
<a href="/search/1080p/t-8/">8</a> 
<a href="/search/1080p/t-9/">9</a> 
<a href="/search/1080p/t-10/">10</a> 
<a href="/search/1080p/t-11/">11</a> 
<a href="/search/1080p/t-12/">12</a> 
<a href="/search/1080p/t-13/">13</a> 
<a href="/search/1080p/t-14/">14</a> 
<a href="/search/1080p/t-15/">15</a> 
<a href="/search/1080p/t-16/">16</a> 
<a href="/search/1080p/t-17/">17</a> 
<a href="/search/1080p/t-18/">18</a> 
<a href="/search/1080p/t-19/">19</a> 
<a href="/search/1080p/t-20/">20</a> 
<a href="/search/1080p/t-21/">21</a> 
<a href="/search/1080p/t-22/">22</a> 
<a href="/search/1080p/t-23/">23</a> 
<a href="/search/1080p/t-2/">Next</a> 
<a href="/search/1080p/t-255/">Last</a>
```

It seems `t-2` is a pointer to the `Next` page, which will contain the rest of the links.